# How to make presence and absence data from point data

Tags: r

I have a point data (Lon and Lat), and I would like to create presence and absence data from it. How can I do this in R? Example is below.

Load data:

```
df <- read.table(text=
"species        lon   lat
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -130.25 55.75
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.75 55.75
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -130.25 55.25
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.75 55.25
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.25 55.25
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -133.25 54.75
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -131.75 54.75
Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -131.25 54.75
",
header=TRUE
)
head(df)

 # create grid
reso = 0.25
xs <- seq(-180, 180, by=reso)
ys <- seq(-90, 90, by=reso)
grd <- expand.grid(
  x=xs,
  y=ys,
  presence=0
)
head(grd)

# query
for(i in seq(nrow(df))){
  tmp <- which(df$lon[i] == grd$x & df$lat[i] == grd$y)
  if(length(tmp)>0){
    grd$presence[tmp] <- 1
  }
}

png("plot.png", width=5, height=5, units="in", res=600, type="cairo")
plot(grd$x, grd$y, pch=1, cex=1, col=c(NA, 1)[grd$presence+1], lwd=0.5)
dev.off()
```

However, this code doesn't work for me when I use irregular Lon and Lat data like this:

```
  Lat            Lon
24.08333    32.88333
30.00486    31.23571
32.5        27.5
33.333     -8.417
34.395      26.05383
34.5       -6.917
35          15
35.0738     32.3335
35.19509    25.71726
35.2047     25.7221
35.26665    26.22368
35.33198    25.39159
```

Comment: can you give us the error you had ? R is case sensitive so if your colnames are Lon and Lat instead of lon and lat the code won't work. In addition in the example the lon and lat vary by 0.25 which is not the case for you so I doubt it can work

Comment: thanks Ronak, i have all has absence ( 0) , no presence data (1). yes the Lon and Lat vary by 0.25. But I want the same grid that was created . thanks

Comment: If you have irregular data, but want data for a regular grid, you'll need some kind of interpolation.

Comment: This is because the Lon/Lat of your points will not exactly match the grid x and y.  You will have to use the ranges for each grid cell rather than the x and y (which define only the centers or corners of your grid).  i.e. use x+/-0.25 and y+/-0.25.  You will have to be careful with your use of < > vs <= and <=.

Comment: Hi cotton, thanks for you input. am really new to R. Please where will I add this in the codes, is it while creating the grids or query for the presence? thanks

Comment: @user5545418, I posted some edited code in an answer below.  Let me know if this is what you are looking for.

Comment: [This Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32889531/r-how-can-i-count-how-many-points-are-in-each-cell-of-my-grid?rq=1) may be relevant. See also `sp::over` (e.g. `x = "SpatialGrid", y = "SpatialPoints"`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because the Lon/Lat of your points will not exactly match the grid x and y.
You will have to use the ranges for each grid cell rather than the x and y (which define only the centers or corners of your grid). i.e. use x+/-0.125 and y+/-0.125.  This assumes that the grid values are for the cell centers, not one of the corners.  You will have to adjust depending on which grid specification you intend.
I changed the values in the data frame to points not on the grid.  Check to see if this works for you:

```
df <- read.table(text=
                      "species        lon   lat
                  Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -130.7 55.95
                  Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.6 55.235
                  Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -130.21 55.34
                  Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.751 55.901
                  Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -129.2509 55.5
                  Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -133.99 54.834
                  Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -131.9 54.75
                  Oncorhynchus_kisutch    -131.25 54.532
                  ",
                 header=TRUE
)
head(df)

 # create grid
reso = 0.25
xs <- seq(-180, 180, by=reso)
ys <- seq(-90, 90, by=reso)
grd <- expand.grid(
  x=xs,
  y=ys,
  presence=0
)
head(grd)

# query
for(i in seq(nrow(df))){
     tmp <- which(df$lon[i] >= grd$x-0.125 & df$lon[i] < grd$x+0.125 & df$lat[i] >= grd$y-0.125 & df$lat[i] < grd$y+0.125)
     if(length(tmp)>0){
         grd$presence[tmp] <- 1
     }
 }
table(grd$presence)
grd[grd$presence==1,]
```

Comment: Hey guys, I ran into another problem. If I use this data set like the one below, I will have all the 1036800 cells as 0( absence). Please help!!!!    Lat        Lon
1  -34.06660   23.05000
2  -34.05000   23.06670
3  -34.01550   25.20500
4  -33.78330   26.43330
6  -29.82440   31.05120
7  -29.23000   31.50000
9  -28.36670   32.40000
10 -26.00000   32.91670
11 -21.39500  149.95500
12 -20.00000   43.00000
13 -11.50000  141.03444
18  12.00000  101.00000
19  13.09250   80.29444
20  14.43300  120.48300
21  18.25000  109.25000
23  18.50000  110.50000
25  19.50000  111.00000

Comment: I can't check why the approach is not working for the new data right now, but you may wish to use a more formal spatial approach using the raster package as shown in the question linked by @Henrik in the comment above.  My edit was just for the most simple solution with slight modification of your code.  Using the raster package is a better way to approach this problem.

Comment: thanks cotton, I did figure where the problem is. many thanks